# What is Window Station?

Tags: windows, window

I have tried to look up in Internet and didn't find answers. Moreover, I didn't understand very well [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx) explanation.

Can someone explain what ***Window Station*** is in simple terms? Where do you use it? When? How do they work?

Comment: @Hennes Isn't the blue screen you mean the [blue screen of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death)?

Answer (score 6):

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/ba-p/372473 seems to cover it - I found it by googling for 'windows station object" (since your article refers to `Each window station object is a securable object` and that seemed like a good place to go deeper)

> A session consists of all of the processes and other system objects
> that represent a single user’s logon session.  These objects include
> all windows, desktops and windows stations.  A desktop is a
> session-specific paged pool area and loads in the kernel memory space.
> This area is where session-private GUI objects are allocated from.  A
> windows station is basically a security boundary to contain desktops
> and processes.  So, a session may contain more than one Windows
> Station and each windows station can have multiple desktops.

Seems to be a useful starting point.

They even have a lovely image showing the relationship between these things

[image]

Essentially a windows station 'contains' the 'desktops' and processes for a user. A session contains a windows station, which contains one or more desktops - with a 'desktop' being a login window, a 'session' of windows as we understand it, or UAC.

The article goes into much more detail (than I can understand tbh) but the windows performance blogs seem to be a much better *in depth* resource for these things.

Comment: Certain tools such as SuRun or KeePass 2.x also employ secure desktops. Because the more important point here is the scope of facilities like [window hooks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks) and how these relate to desktops and window stations. So while technically correct, your answer kind of misses the most important aspect of sessions, window stations and desktops: [security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/initializing-winlogon). "Securable" in that sense means ACL with ACEs (auditing and access control).

Comment: Better answers are always welcome ;). Might even toss a bounty that way if I'm impressed.